# Ruby button action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method in a controller file that I want activated only when a button is pressed.

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= button_to 'Export POINT', :controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'create_file_txt' %>
```

**my_controller.erb**

```
def create_file_txt 
.
.
end
```

**init.rb**

```
permission :view_button_exp, {:controller => :my_controller, :action => :create_file_txt}, :require => :member
```

Comment: So whats the problem? Please post an error log or describe the error.

Comment: that's what i do, but i don't know why it's not working so any ideas?
thanks

Comment: do you get any error, is there any log output?

Comment: The problem that i don't have any errors and it's not running also